# Unresolveable build extension: Tycho cannot resolve dependency to bundle although present in the target file

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.26.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:0.26.0

below is my pom.xml file

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.in2soft.otx.checker
    com.kpit.otx.checker.build
    1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<properties>
    <tycho-version>0.26.0</tycho-version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Mars</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
            </configuration>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>${os}</os>
                        <ws>${ws}</ws>
                        <arch>${arch}</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
                <target>
                    <artifact>
                        <groupId>com.in2soft.otx.checker</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rcp</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <classifier>rcp</classifier>
                    </artifact>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```